# URL Query String Causes Layout to Break

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, wordpress, url

I have an Apache server based Wordpress site that rewrites URLs to be "pretty".

When I include a query parameter in the url the site breaks.

So:

```
http://mysite.com
```

works fine but:

```
http://mysite.com/?anything
```

Does not... loading the page contents but failing to load some plugins that I use on the home page.

If you can explain why this happens I would love to hear it. Failing that I would just like to strip off the query parameters entirely so that a request to:

```
http://mysite.com/?anything
```

would behave just like the request to:

```
http://mysite.com
```

Either through redirection or through simply removing the query string.

Here is my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Handle redirection from https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
# End https to http redirection

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^index.php$
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Before you "move on" would you please [mark an accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Comment: Well... it feels wrong to accept myself as the correct answer but since a mod edited my question to remove the answer I will add it below.

Comment: It's "wrong" to leave a question "unaccepted" when you've got the correct answer. ;)  Self-answer is encouraged, even rewarded, on SE sites.  In fact, they build in [support for quicker handling](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886/what-is-this-answer-your-own-question-jazz) of such cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I answered the question myself and then that was edited out of my question I will enter it as an "own answer".

Adding the below solved my issue:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Lothar_Grimpsenbacher,

So I think it might not be an .htaccess problem, might be a WordPress miss concept. I will try to explain briefly;

WordPress has some query_vars that comes from the variables, and if you have the "pretty" permalinks activated (looks like you do from the rules of your .htaccess), the problem would be that the `?anything` is a GET parameter not expected, so WordPress might think it's a case for a 404 depending on what are the variables.

As far as I can tell I wouldn't mess with the .htaccess files just to solve this simple problem, might give you serious problems later on.

I think the solution for your problem lies around WordPress been able to see that the variable passed is valid, check the solution below:

```
function prefix_add_query_vars() {
    global $wp;
    $wp->add_query_var('anything');
}

add_filter('init', 'prefix_add_query_vars');
```

And within your template page you can check for the value like this:

```
if ( get_query_var('anything') ) {
    //do your stuff
}
```

PS: I'm not good with .htaccess file rules my self...

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?[^\ ]+
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

(per the author)